# O aplicativo para quando o editText não é preenchido

Tags: android, edittext, equações

Olá! Gostaria de pedir uma ajuda. Sou novo no Android studio e estou tentando criar um aplicativo para os meus alunos de física a calcular equações de movimento. Um dos métodos é calcular a equação "V=v0+at", quando os editTexts são preenchidos funciona normal, mas quando um fica vazio o aplicativo para.
Já tentei de várias formas usar métodos que identificam variáveis vazias mas nunca dá certo.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
public void velocidadeTempo(View view){
    setContentView(R.layout.velocidade_tempo);

    final EditText editV0 = findViewById(R.id.editv0);
    final EditText editA = findViewById(R.id.edita);
    final EditText editT = findViewById(R.id.editt);

    final TextView tvV1 = findViewById(R.id.tvResultado);


    final double[] velocidadeF = new double[1];

    Button btcalcular = findViewById(R.id.btCalcular);

    btcalcular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String numv0 = editV0.getText().toString();
            double v0 = Double.parseDouble(numv0);

            String numa = editA.getText().toString();
            double a = Double.parseDouble(numa);

            String numt = editT.getText().toString();
            double t = Double.parseDouble(numt);

            velocidadeF[0] = v0 + (a*t);

            if(editV0.getText().toString().isEmpty()||editA.getText().toString().isEmpty()||editT.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                tvV1.setText("sem resposta");
            }else{
                tvV1.setText(velocidadeF[0]+"");
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Lembrando que o valor "0" é válido na equação.

Answer (score 1):

Quando o conteúdo de um EditText é utilizado numa operação matemática é necessário garantir, pelo menos, que:

- não é nulo

  ```
  if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
      // O conteúdo é nulo
  }
  ```
- representa um valor numérico

  ```
  <EditText
     android:id="@+id/edittext"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="0" 
     android:inputType="number"/>
  ```

  O atributo `android:text="0"` atribui o valor zero como valor por padrão.
  O atributo `android:inputType="number"` faz com que apenas valores inteiros seja aceites pelo EditText.

Estas validações têm de ser feitas antes da conversão(*parse*) do conteúdo(String) para o correspondente valor numérico.

Outras validações poderão ser necessárias em função do tipo de cálculo a efectuar.

Answer (score 0):

Eu usei isso aqui, modifique o seu código e ver se funciona

```
if(!email.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !senha.getText().toString().isEmpty())
   validarLogin();
else
   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Um ou mais campos estão vazios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```